# Upper limit on dimensionality of space?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Is there an upper limit on the possible dimensionality of space?
Apparently, it looks like for any cardinality *n*, if *n*-dimensional space is (mathematically) possible, then so is $2^{n}$-dimensional space.
Is there *any* reason to think otherwise?

Comment: Mathematically, any number of dimensions is possible: just keep adding coordinates. Indeed, there are even *infinite-dimensional* spaces.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The vector space of all real-valued functions of a real variable has uncountably infinite dimension.

Comment: Hilbert space is the infinite dimensional analog of n-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the comments & the answer, Anti?

Comment: Earth to Anti: come in, please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. Sorry for the late reply. I was curious if there is, say, an aleph-4 dimensional space. I know infinite dimensional spaces exist, but I think it's another question to ask whether for any infinite cardinal, there is a space whose dimensionality is that infinite cardinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any cardinal number you like (finite or infinite) there is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ with that cardinal as its dimension. There is no bound at all; why would there be?